# Putting a Slick2D game inside a GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, lwjgl, slick2d

What I am trying to do is to create a GUI using SWING and then have a container that will display the actual Slick game inside as seen below.

[image: Example]

The problem is that the AppGameContainer is the only available container (that I know of) but that creates the whole window (which includes the title bar and stuff) so I can't really embed that inside the GUI, could I? I'm open to other solutions as well so let me know if there is a better way to achieve this.

I am not very experienced with Slick2D so sorry if it's obvious but I tried Googling it and didn't come up with anything.

Comment: Just for the shake of another option you can have a look on [OpenGl](http://www.codersource.net/2011/02/06/a-simple-2d-game-with-opengl-ball-with-bat/).

Comment: Because it's based on lwjgl, I suspect it's using a java.awt.Canvas at the core, this makes it a heavy weight component, which doesn't always play nice in Swing, just as a heads up

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an OpenGL Frame Buffer Object (FBO) to render your scene to. An FBO acts like a 2D texture object in OpenGL, so you could then read the pixel data from the FBO and use it to render to a Buffered Image, and use that to render to your java swing canvas. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21UsMuFTN0k)
is a pretty good tutorial on how to use FBOs if you choose to implement this strategy.